# WebKit view web WhatsApp not keep logged in

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

in my app, I am using WebKit to open the web WhatsApp but when the user goes back it logged out how I can keep the user logged in to WhatsApp.

Comment: Are you really using `UIWebView` like you tagged? That was deprecated in iOS 12

Comment: Nope, I am using WebKit

Comment: That is not clear -- WebKit is the underlying technology for all web views on iOS. Do you mean `WKWebView`? `SFSafariViewController`? It would be helpful to show the relevant code.

Comment: yes, I am talking about WKWebView.

Comment: Please see [ask] and include the relevant code, ideally in a [mre].